# fallback.io doesnt work with scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cdn, fallback

I wanted to use the fallback.js from fallback.io, so I used the documentation from github. How ever the issue is that it works just the css and font files but it doesn't work for all my js scripts.

```
<script src="media/js/fallback.min.js"></script>
<script>
    fallback.load({

        'jquery-2.1.3.js': [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js',
            'media/js/jquery-2.1.3.js'
        ],

        'bootstrap.min.js': [
            '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js',
            'media/js/jquery-2.1.3.js'
        ],

        'smoothscroll.js': 'media/js/smoothscroll.js',

            'bootstrap.min.css': [
                '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                'media/css/bootstrap.min.css'
            ],

            'bootstrap-theme.min.css': [
                '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
                'media/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
            ],

            'media.css': [
                'media/css/media.css'
            ],

            'Montesserat-Regular.ttf': [
                '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat',
                'media/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'
            ] 
    }, 
    {
        // Shim jQuery UI so that it will only load after jQuery has completed!
        //'jQuery.ui': ['jQuery']
        shim: {
            'bootstrap.min.js': ['jquery-2.1.3.js'],
            'media.css': ['bootstrap.min.css'],
        },

        //callback: function(failed) {
            // success - object containing all libraries that loaded successfully.
            // failed - object containing all libraries that failed to load.
            // All of my libraries have finished loading!
            // Execute my code that applies to all of my libraries here!
        //}
    });

    //fallback.ready(['jquery-2.1.3.js'], function() {
        // jQuery Finished Loading
        // Execute my jQuery dependent code here! });

    //fallback.ready(['jQuery', 'JSON'], function() {
        // jQuery and JSON Finished Loading

        // Execute my jQuery + JSON dependent code here! });

    fallback.ready(['jquery-2.1.3.js', 'bootstrap.min.js'], function() {
        // All of my libraries have finished loading!
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 1000,
            pause: hover,
            wrap: true,
            keyboard: true
        })
        // Execute my code that applies to all of my libraries here!
    });
</script>
</head>
```

What did I do wrong?
And which fallback do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [fallback.io docs](https://github.com/dolox/fallback/blob/v1/README.md#fallbackloadlibraries-options), the keys in your `fallback.load` list must be some variable name that's exposed by the javascript library you're loading.

> fallback.load({libraries}, {options})
>
> Expects to be an object containing a key value pair where the key is
>   the library's window variable, and the value is the url to fetch the
>   library from. The keys must be the window variable name of the library
>   you're loading if it's a JavaScript library. This is only relevant for
>   JavaScript libraries and not StyleSheets, for StyleSheets you can name
>   them however you please. For example jQuery's key would be jQuery
>   since window.jQuery exists after jQuery has finished loading. This is
>   required to provide support for legacy browsers.

So instead of doing

```
'jquery-2.1.3.js': [
                '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js',
                'media/js/jquery-2.1.3.js'
            ],
```

you should use

```
'jQuery': [
                '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js',
                'media/js/jquery-2.1.3.js'
            ],
```